# What should DELETE /collection do if some items can't be deleted?

Tags: rest, design-patterns

I have a collection of items and some of them may or may not be deleted, depending on some preconditions. If a user wants to delete a resource (`DELETE /collection/1`) and there are external dependencies on that resource, the server will return an error. But what should happen if the user wants to delete the entire collection (`DELETE /collection`)?

Should all the resources which can be deleted be deleted and the server return a 2xx, or should the server leave everything intact and return a 4xx? Which would be the expected behavior?

Comment: Ideally it's atomic, so all or nothing. That would be my expectation. But sometimes, that is not possible to implement. Either way, make it clear in the API documentation.

Comment: It's a difficult one, DELETE is an idempotent operation, i.e. multiple calls to the same resource should result in the server being in the same state, so @Thilo is right in the sense that should behave atomically.

Comment: I agree with Thilo. It should be atomic. So, in you case Delete/Collection doesn't make sense. Rather say Delete/Collection/NoDependencies. That seems to be more like expected behaviour.

Comment: @jbarrueta 1.) it removes everything, 2.) it removes nothing, 3.) it removes the items it can remove. Seems like always idempotent to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a REST API consumer, I'd expect the operation to be atomic and maybe get back a `409 Conflict` with details if one of the deletes fails. Plus the DELETE method is theoretically idempotent as @jbarrueta pointed out.

Now if undeletable resources is a normal event in your use case and happens frequently, you may want to stray from the norm a little bit, delete all that can be deleted and return something like a `206 Partial Content` (don't know if that's legal for DELETE though) with details about undeleted resources.

However, if you need to manage error cases finely, you might be better off sending separate DELETE commands.

Comment: *I'd expect the operation to be atomic* - I'll go with this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper result is 204 no content by success and 409 conflict by failure because of the dependencies (as the others pointed out). I support atomicity as well.

I think you are thinking about REST as SOAP/RPC, which it is clearly not. Your REST service MUST fulfill the uniform interface constraint, which includes the HATEOAS interface constraint, so you MUST send hyperlinks to the client.

1. If we are talking about a simple link, like `DELETE /collection`, then you must send the link to the client, only if the resource state transition it represents, is available from the current resource state. So if you cannot delete the collection because of the dependencies, then you don't send a link about this transition, because it is not possible.
2. If it is a templated link, then you have to attach the "removable" property to the items, and set the checkboxes to disabled if it is false.

This way conflict happens only when the client got the link from a representation of a previous (stale) resource state, and in that case you must update the client state by querying the server again with GET.

3. Another possible solution (ofc. in combination with the previous ones) to show the link and automatically remove dependencies.
4. I guess you can use PATCH for bulk updates, which includes bulk removal, so that can be another solution as well.

Comment: point 1.) violates statelessness: always send all potentially possible operations. Using PATCH for DELETE sounds like a bad hack since delete is naturally idempotent, so where's the gain in using PATCH?

Comment: @mnemosyn I need some explanation about how it violates statelessness, because it does not. "always send all potentially possible operations" - Yes, I meant the same, but if the operation is not possible, then don't send it. There is no gain in using PATCH, it is just a 4th option, I would recommend the 1. and 2.

Comment: If the `DELETE` link is missing, you're telling me: "delete isn't possible on the collection *right now*". But that might not even be true anymore once I receive the result, i.e. you're telling me about a part of the application state that I can't see as a client. If I make another GET, for instance, it's possible that the delete link suddenly appears, though nobody has modified the collection. Doesn't that make it stateful, in a way?

Comment: @mnemosyn "If I make another GET, for instance, it's possible that the delete link suddenly appears, though nobody has modified the collection." - That is possible only if the resource state has changed meanwhile, so somebody modified the collection. Still not stateful...

Comment: You're *hiding* an operation from me as a client without me being able to influence or detect that. Moreover, it's well possible that the resource is locked because one of its items is referenced by another resource in another collection, so nobody has to modify *this* collection... Sounds stateful to me.

Comment: @mnemosyn Btw. you use HATEOAS because of 2 things: decoupling the client from the implementation of the service and hiding operations, which are not available at the current time for the current user. In contrast by SOAP you got a WSDL, which contains non-available operations as well.

Comment: @mnemosyn "because one of its items is referenced by another resource in another collection, so nobody has to modify this collection" - resource state is not about only "this collection", it is about every resource maintained by the service, summed up. I will add some references about this if you really need it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77898/discussion-between-mnemosyn-and-inf3rno).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on your domain (although I'd rather use `DELETE /collection/all` instead of `DELETE/collection/`),

When you have the situation where you use delete all but some items can't be deleted, it depends on your domain where if you are doing the delete all to free up resources where if not your business process suffers, then it's better to delete what can be deleted and put other into a retry queue makes sense. in that case response should be OK.

Also situations could arise where there could be two operations

1. Clean Up - only delete unused
2. Delete All - delete all

In either situation I'd rather use specific method rather than using `DELETE` on the root URL,

for Clean Up - `DELETE /collection/unused`

for Delete ALL - `DELETE /collection/all`